recursively find all directories *primarily* occupied with images
I'm working on a very unorganized archive of a friend spanning many years and with a lot of duplication and compicated structure. I want to split the archive into directories that are primarily occupied with photos and videos and upload them to an immich server. And then upload the rest to a seafile server.
Before going into building my own logic, I wanted to ask if anything ready or half-ready exists over there.
The complication is that directories with photos and videos may contain occasionally other files like thumbnails, "DS_Store" and similar garbage. So I can't rely that these will be only image and video files.
Also in other directories there might occasionally be image files but that are not to be part of the photo archive. For example his audio recordings with some images of work-in-progress CD cover. Also means audio and video files related to his CDs should stay in the file archive, not the immich server.
Basically looking for suggestions to make this separation process less cumbersome.
PS Recursively list all directories that contain one or more jpg image files is slightly related but not really up to the task here

You can either filter the file name of the file type, to automate such task, Unless there are more details to follow.

In zsh:
has_mostly_images() {
  emulate -L zsh -o extendedglob
  local non_hidden_regular_files images
  non_hidden_regular_files=( $REPLY/*(NoN-.) )
  images=( ${(M)non_hidden_regular_files:#*.(#i)(jp(e|)g|png|gif|tif(|f)|svg|bmp)} )
  (( $#non_hidden_regular_files && $#images * 100 / $#non_hidden_regular_files >= 80 ))
}
print -rC1 -- **/*(NDF+has_mostly_images)

Would print the list of directories where 80% or more of the non-hidden regular files have an extension from the most common image file types.

Works like a charm. I had to add mov, mp4 and thm extensions to the list butit seems to be catching most if not all of the stuff. I guess I need to also check this list of folders for other types of files, to see if they need to be preserved. Thank you!

Actually seems like I need the whole subdirectory tree to be mostly images... I don't know zsh, can this script easily be modified like this?

@akostadinov, you could replace $REPLY/*(NoN-.) with $REPLY/**/*(NoN-.) but that's likely going to get expensive, and you'll find that path/to/img and path/to/img/subdir-with-imgs are going to be both reported. Ideally, you'd want to skip looking for matching subdirs once a directory is found matching, but that would likely mean using a wholly different approach. Would be worth asking a separate follow-up question.

I see you saw my eventual answer. Thanks for catching the bug and editing it!

The statement "primarily occupied with images" is a vague statement and therefore almost impossible to implement. You need to put this into a criterium that is more specific. You could try to classify the directory:
for d in * ; do
    echo -n "$d"
    q=$(ls -1 "$d" | wc-l)
    q_JPG=$(ls -1 "$d".JPG | wc-l)
    q_CR2=$(ls -1 "$d".CR2 | wc-l)
    q_MOV=$(ls -1 "$d".MOV | wc-l)
    if [[ $((100*(q_JPG+q_CR2)/q)) -gt 75 ]] ; then
        echo "Image directory"
    elif [[ $((100*q_MOV/q)) -gt 75 ]] ; then
        echo "Video directory"
    fi
done

You will need to create your own loop to go through the directories; the for loop is an example only.  You will also need to create the exact criteria for primarily occupied with images. For example: you might consider it to be a cd-rip, if there are 2 mp3's in the directory, even if the complete booklet is scanned to jpeg.

You're right; made the change to the answer.

Eventually I wrote a ruby script that will read file list from stdin and output dirs with the desired percent images but not subdirs of such dirs. Each output line starts with the percent number followed by the file name.
Then I it was manageable to go over the list manually to remove false positives.
#!/bin/env ruby

# Feed it list of files, e.g. find -t file

class Counter
  DESIRED_PERCENT_IMAGES = 90
  IMAGE_PATTERN = /\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|tiff?|svg|bmp|mov|mp4|avi|thm)$/i

  attr_accessor :parent
  attr_accessor :images, :non_images

  def initialize(parent)
    @parent = parent
    @images = 0
    @non_images = 0
  end

  def increment(path)
    image?(path) ? increment_images : increment_non_images
  end

  def percent
    return 0 if images < 3

    images * 100 / (images + non_images)
  end

  def mostly_images?
    percent >= DESIRED_PERCENT_IMAGES
  end

  def parent_with_mostly_images?
    parent&.mostly_images? || parent&.parent_with_mostly_images?
  end

  protected

  def increment_images
    self.images += 1
    parent&.increment_images
  end

  def increment_non_images
    self.non_images += 1
    parent&.increment_non_images
  end

  def image?(path)
    IMAGE_PATTERN.match? path
  end
end

def populate_counters(dir, counts)
  return counts[dir] = Counter.new(nil) if %w[. /].include?(dir)

  parent_dir = File.dirname(dir)
  parent = counts[parent_dir] || populate_counters(parent_dir, counts)
  counts[dir] = Counter.new(parent)
end

counts = Hash.new

warn "Counting.."
while file = gets
  dir = File.dirname(file)
  counter = counts[dir] || populate_counters(dir, counts)

  counter.increment(file)
end

warn "Outputting results.."
counts.each do |dir, counter|
  puts "#{counter.percent} #{dir}" if counter.mostly_images? && !counter.parent_with_mostly_images?
end

If you don't want to install ruby on your machine you can run like:
find PATH1 PATH2 -type f | podman run -i --rm --name counter -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp docker.io/ruby:3.3 ruby find_mostly_images.rb > /tmp/mostly_images.lst

This assumes the above script is called find_mostly_images.rb and is present in current directory.
